# Server Instance is not configured : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I am running apache Tomcat server on webclipse but everytime I run above error occurs. I fixed this error by removing the `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>`     tag in `server.xml` under the directory `Wrokspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf`. But it can be fixed only once. If I wnat to run again, I must remove the tag again. What are the alternative methods to solve this problem? Please help me. This is the `server.xml` under `Wrokspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf`

server.xml under wrokspace
[image: server.xml under wrokspace]
and this is the image under tomcat cofig folder

server.xml under tomcat cofig folder
[image: server.xml under tomcat cofig folder]

Comment: Did you recently upgrade or downgrade Tomcat? Did you use your old `server.xml` when you did that upgrade/downgrade?

Comment: I didn't upgrade the Tomcat. First I downloaded apache tomcat 7.0.78 from the apache website and set environment and confirmed tomcat is running by calling from the web browser. Then I added the apache 7.0 server to eclipse from eclipse market place and clicked download and installed link. What is gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the `VersionLoggingListener` then something in your Tomcat package has been damaged, and you likely need to reinstall it. It's also possible that Eclipse is not actually running the Tomcat you think it is running.